# How to instruct autopep8 to remove line breaks?

Tags: python, autopep8

How to instruct autopep8 python formatter to remove line breaks if the resulting line after removing the line breaks does not exceed the maximum allowed line length?
For example, I have the following code that was previously formatted with `--max-line-length 80`:

```
def function(a, b, c):
    pass


function('VERYLOOOOOOOOOOOOONGSTRING',
         'VERYLOOOOOOOOOOOOONGSTRING', 'VERYLOOOOOOOOOOOOONGSTRING')
```

Now maximum line length is 120. I want `autopep8 -i --max-line-length 120 test.py` to format it like this:

```
def function(a, b, c):
    pass


function('VERYLOOOOOOOOOOOOONGSTRING', 'VERYLOOOOOOOOOOOOONGSTRING', 'VERYLOOOOOOOOOOOOONGSTRING')
```

But it does not remove line breaks. Adding multiple `--aggressive` options does not help either.

If it's not possible do to with autopep8, what other formatters/software can I use to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think `autopep8` has this feature, as PEP 8 doesn't concern itself with ensuring lines have  *minimum* length. Recommendations for other tools is explicitly  off-topic.

Comment: (this is going to be closed as "seeking recommendation for software tools", probably, and autopep8 doesn't support this) you may consider using other formatters like `black` (or it's fork `blue` with single quote preference) and `yapf`.